# Angular drag and drop cannot drag to correct position in mat dialog

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I have a long list of items and would like to drag and drop them to change position in the list.

If it is used in a simple component, I can drag and drop it in any position. During drag, I can scroll to the items which are outside the visible range and i can drop to the scrolled items.

But when I put the list in the mat dialog. I can drag and drop in the visible range. If drag to the scrolled items, the position to drop becomes wrong.

This is the issue recording http://g.recordit.co/FMMLqC69g4.gif
This is the cdkDropList does not set height and overflow-y in the parent div.

I made a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-droplist-mat-dialog-issue-angualr-12)

I modify the stackblitz again. If the cdkDropList is under the  of height and overflow-y: scroll set, then the drag and drop not working as expected.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or any workaround. I found some of the workaround solutions, none of them works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i know the root cause and know how to solve it. I need to set the height of the div that use cdkDropList.

This is the [stackblitz solve example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-droplist-mat-dialog-solve)

Although i fixed the wrong position issue, but i still want the scroll bar to appear in the div i wanted not in the cdkDropList div.